# unbind some function when there are some li's elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to turn on and turn off one .click function.
This is my jquery code:

```
$('.original li').on('click',clonaCol);

$('.anade li').on('click',desselec);


var numeroli;

var max=3;
var numero;

$('.original').on('click', function(){ 

    numeroli = $('#count').children("li").length; alert(numeroli);

    if(numeroli>=3){
        $('.original li').off('click',clonaCol);
    }
    else{
        $('#dialog').show();
    }    

});
```

with this code I can exchange the li elements between two columns, but my problem is I can't stop the first function where I pass the li to the second ul, and when there are 3 elements on the second ul, goes off warning text and advance the test.

Comment: you should provide a jsFiddle, quite unclear what is your issue

Comment: Sorry if i've been unclear. I didn't use jsFiddle because i'm ussing sass and it doesn't work with this, doesn't work js functions which works in firefox or opera.

I'm trying to unbind some function when there are more than 3 elements.

Comment: so just copy/paste rendered CSS as in your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to follow, and would be easier with a fiddle, but I'm pretty sure the problem is that events bubble UP so your handler attached to .original will always run AFTER the handler attached to .original li.  Basically, that means as you have it written when you click on a list item in your .original ul, the click event for the li runs the function clonaCol THEN the event bubbles to .original and you unbind the click event handler.

To fix this you can do your check in the list item handler and return false or display your dialog or whatever you're trying to do if there are more than 3 li.  Something like this:

```
$('.original li').on('click',function () {
  if ($('#count li').length>=3) {
    $('#dialog').show();
  } else {
    clonaCol();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you and I'm so sorry if I didn't express ok.

Comment: There's no need to be sorry.  I'm happy if my answer helped you. Much luck to you.